# MySQL Connector NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE Error

Tags: python, mysql, ssl

I am using the MySQL connector to create a connection for my simple python app however every time I run it, it fails and returns the following error:

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '{databaseHost}', system error: 1 [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:997)
```

The code for the connection object that I am using is as follows:

```
self.mydbConnection = mysql.connector.connect(user="{username}", password="{password}", host="{dbHost}", port={dbPort}, database="{dbName}", ssl_ca=r"{certLocation}")
```

To add some more context the database I am trying to connect to is an azure MySQL database and I have already enabled TLS versions 1, 1.1, and 1.2 on it.

What confuses me more is that if I try to run the code on another computer it works just fine.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, both are running on version 2.2.9 of MySQL connector

Comment: What version of Python are you on? I ran into the exact same issue on 3.10 and any version <3.10 worked fine in my case. Haven't gotten the root-cause though.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work when I changed the module for mySQL from mysql-connector to  mysql-connector-python! It shouldn't change the connector call (: